# Using Python to report excel

Tags: python, excel, split, report, filenames

I am new to python and I have a folder with 8 different Excel files in which I want to read the files and write combined into a new workbook and also have a new workbook with two different sheets splitting the files based on the name. The filename:
True Reported.xls,False Reported.xls,True Not Reported.xls,False Not Reported.xls etc So I want to combine all Reported in a sheet and all the Not Reported in another sheet within the same workbook.Please help out

Comment: Could you show us what have you tried so far? So we can help you at where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks alot someone has helped out already.

Answer (score 0):

you can use openpyxl library and do this with effortless.
here is cookbook:
https://realpython.com/openpyxl-excel-spreadsheets-python/

Comment: Thanks so much. The material helped alot

Comment: my pleasure  to help.